# Can't refresh webquery in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, web-services, excel-2016, office-2016, excel-web-query

Since a few weeks I am using Office 2016 and I have a few Excel spreadsheets that collect data from my own webservice using a web query. As you can see, the webservice has the right properties in the connections dialog:

[image: connectinos]

When I refresh, I always get the following error message:
[image]

It's in Dutch, but the error message says "Can't find Data Source". As you can see, the url of the webservice is not fully displayed. I can't find anything about it on Google, but did the length of a valid web query url change in the new version of Excel?

It works perfectly fine in Excel 2013 and Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

After applying the Office Click-To-Run update (1609) to Excel 2016, I experience the same issue. It works in previous Excel versions, including 2013 and 2010. It seems a part of the URL in the GET request Excel makes is cut off.

By rolling back Office Click-To-Run update (1609), the problem disappears.

I have ended up working around this by shortening my URL's. This is probably only a solution to others if they can use an URL-shortening service (TinyUrl) or have control of the webservice.

It really seems like an Excel bug.